# please help me evaluate this limit

Tags: calculus

How to calculate$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \Big({x^2}\int\limits_0^x {{e^{{t^3} - {x^3}}}} dt\Big)?$$

Comment: What have you tried? What are your insights on this problem? We like to help, but we can't solve your exercises for you...

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{1}x^3 e^{x^3 (t^3-1)}\,dt=\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{1}x^3 (1-u)^{-2/3}e^{-ux^3}\,du=\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{x^3}\left(1-\frac{v}{x^3}\right)^{-2/3}e^{-v}\,dv $$
as $x\to +\infty$, converges to $\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-v}\,dv$ by the dominated convergence theorem. An alternative approach is to exploit de l'Hopital's rule and compute $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{e^{x^3}}{\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{e^{x^3}}{x^2}\right)}$.

Comment: Thank you I will keep what you said in mind while posting other questions

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

take ${e^{-x^3}}$ to denominator.

Now as x tends to infinity, you have infinity/infinity form.

Apply L'Hospital and differentiate numerator and denominator. Terms will cancel out.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:$$\lim_{x \to \infty } \left({x^2}\int\limits_0^x {{e^{{t^3} - {x^3}}}} dt\right)\\=\lim_{x \to \infty } \left({x^2}\int\limits_0^x {{e^{{t^3}}}} \frac{1}{e^{x^3}}\,dt\right)\\=\lim_{x \to \infty } \left(\frac{{x^2}}{e^{x^3}}\int\limits_0^x {{e^{{t^3}}}}\,dt\right)$$

Comment: I get it now thank you